# How to disable current input box, from mapped input boxes

Tags: reactjs

I am in a middle of project, and I have an array containing id, product, price and mapped that array which returns many input field and values that I need from that array

what's happening , when I write in one of the input field it reflects the same value to all those mapped input field,

Same if with any function I execute, for example, I passed a function which disables the input tag, but on clicking the respective button, all input tag got disabled!!

Only solution I know is to use key, but how to do that, what is the correct way of passing index value of map function into key ?
and where to use that key?

Here is a smaill example of my actuall code.

```js
function Stack() {
    const productArr = [{ Product: "TV", Price: 100 }, { Product: "watch", Price: 200 }, { Product: "mobile", Price: 300 }, { Product: "Pc", Price: 400 }]

    const [value, setValue] = useState("");
    const [disable, setDisable] = useState(false);

    const disableHandler = () => {
        setDisable(true)
    }

    const ProductArr = productArr.map((data, index) => {
        return (
            <tbody key={index}>
                <tr>
                    <td>{index + 1}</td>
                    <td>{data.Product}</td>
                    <td>{data.Price}</td>
                    <td key={index}  > <input type="text" disabled={disable}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                            setValue(e.target.value)
                        }}
                        value={value}
                    /> </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        );
    });
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={disableHandler} > disable </button>{/* to disable current value but all got disabled */}

            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Sr. no.</th>
                        <th>Product</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Input</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                {ProductArr}
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}
```

please let me know the correct way?

Comment: i just want learn how to use of key in such cases , how to stop reflection ! that's it

Comment: Seems like you have an array of object for your products, but only a single value for your ```value``` and ```disable``` variables. And this single value is being used across the whole array of your product objects

Comment: yes , you are correct.................. I need an another array for value , since I need user to dynamically enter values and on disable the input should disabled..

Comment: since the actual scenario are combination of above question, I am confused what to do , where to do...please tell me what and where to improve.

Comment: I tried to push, concat , even append (which error:append is not a function).. non resulted me well .... but they gave me bugs!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your value, this should work. In the `onChange` function of the input, I copy the contect of the productArr, replace the element that has been changed with the same element with added value to it, and set the productArr to the new array

https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-chatelet-s9u2r?file=/src/Stack.js

For the disable action, I'm not sure how this should behave. What row should be disabled when you click on it?

**Edit**

Updated the codesandbox with the disabled condition. If the disable button is clicked, we set the disable variable to true, so the condition is
`disable && data.value` to only disable rows with values.

Comment: the one which contains data , should be disabled ....... but  now I have a Idea  how do it.........Anyway thank you very much!!

Comment: Ok, so you can do some filtering to see where the value is and set disabled there. I will update the code sandbox